# How to remove selected Column in DataGrid? (C#/WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

How to remove selected Column (and its lines) in DataGrid?

Selection of checkboxes and Excel Record:

```
CsvGrid.SelectAllCells();
foreach (var checkBox in CheckBoxes.Children.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(x => x.IsChecked == true))
{
    for(int i = 0; i < CsvGrid.SelectedCells.Count; i++)
    {
        if (checkBox.Tag != CsvGrid.Columns[i].Header) // How to remove this Column and its lines?
    }
}
ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, CsvGrid);
String result = (string) Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
CsvGrid.UnselectAllCells();

SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog.FileName = "Document";
saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = ".xls";
saveFileDialog.Filter = "Excel|*.xls|Excel 2010|*.xlsx|CSV files (*.csv)|*.CSV";
saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog.FileName, result.Replace(',', ' '));
    MessageBox.Show("File created!");
}
```

Read CSV Table. Writing to DataTable using LumenWorks

```
using LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv;

DataTable csvTable = new DataTable();
using (CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(FilePath.Text), true))
{
    csvTable.Load(csvReader);

    for (int i = 0; i < csvTable.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        csvTable.Columns[i].ColumnName = csvTable.Columns[i].ColumnName.Replace("_", " ");
    }

    CsvGrid.ItemsSource = csvTable.DefaultView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CsvGrid.Items.Refresh();
CsvGrid.UpdateLayout();

for (int i = 0; i < CsvGrid.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    foreach (var checkBox in CheckBoxes.Children.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(x => x.IsChecked == true))
    {
        if (CsvGrid.Columns[i].Header.ToString() == checkBox.Tag.ToString()) CsvGrid.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
     }
}

CsvGrid.SelectAllCells();
CsvGrid.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, CsvGrid);
String result = (string) Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
CsvGrid.UnselectAllCells();

SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog.FileName = "Document";
saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = ".xls";
saveFileDialog.Filter = "Excel|*.xls|Excel 2010|*.xlsx|CSV files (*.csv)|*.CSV";
saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog.FileName, result.Replace(',', ' '));
    MessageBox.Show("File created!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the visibility to collapsed:

```
CsvGrid.Columns[i].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Changing the binding source:

WPF:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="TheGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding dataTable}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Tag="2" Checked="Remove_me"></CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
   DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

   public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dt1 = new DataTable();

        dt1.Columns.Add("1");

        dt1.Columns.Add("2");

        dt1.Columns.Add("3");

        DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();

        TheGrid.ItemsSource = dt1.DefaultView;
    }
    private void Remove_me(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
        dt1.Columns.Remove(checkbox.Tag.ToString())

        TheGrid.ItemsSource = null;
        TheGrid.ItemsSource = dt1.DefaultView;

    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. Then I write this data in .xml

Comment: I see. In that case you'll have no other option than to remove the unwanted columns from the binding source.

Comment: Can you add the code that you use to populate your datagrid?

Comment: Updated question!

Comment: Added an example of removing columns from the binding source. In this case a datatable.